# E: Unable to locate package libstdc++-12-dev

Tags: 20.04, docker

I cannot find libstdc++12-dev or any of the previous versions on the docker container of Ubuntu20.04.

I tried to run `sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 you have `libstdc++-10-dev` available.

Always remember to do a `apt update` in a fresh docker-container since the package cache is not built up in the image.

After that you should be able to install the library by doing:

```shell
$# apt install libstdc++-10-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04 is an option. libstdc++-12-dev can be installed from the default repositories with `sudo apt install libstdc++-12-dev` in Ubuntu 22.04 or later.